# Removing big amount of data

Tags: android

**==========PROBLEM==========**

I am trying to delete a folder that contains a lot of data (mp3, images, xml, ect.). At the moment I am doing it via `FileUtils.removeDirectory()` from `commons-io` library.
The problem is that when I'm doing it, it basically freezes my app.
Is there a way to do it more efficient? or less painfully?

**=========CODE==========**

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String error = null;
    try {
        File internalData = new File(context.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath() + "/download/");
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(internalData);
        File externalData = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + "/Media/");
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(externalData);
        externalData.delete();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        error = e.getMessage();
    }
    return error;
}
```

Comment: Do it inside a thread instead of UI tread

Comment: @MortezaSoleimani `doInBackground` suggests its inside AsyncTask. If it still freezes your app then either you have some kind of logic bug that blocks your UI, or maybe you must rewrite deleting of files/folder yourself and add some Sleep calls to make other threads have chance to take over CPU.

Comment: The thing is that I do it when user is logging out. The only thing that's happening is removing the files and clearing database from some of the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Function:    
public boolean performOnBackgroundThread() {
boolean error=true;
final Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
        File internalData = new File(context.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath() + "/download/");
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(internalData);
        File externalData = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + "/Media/");
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(externalData);
        externalData.delete();
        error = false;
        } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        error = true;            
        }
    }
};
t.start();
return error;
}
```

Comment: As u can see my code is inside `AsyncTask`, therefore this change would be pointless.